# pandas: add missing timestamp into data frame with a default value

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, timestamp, missing-data

I am using the following code to put data into a data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['time', 'value'])

for x in data0.data:
    df = df.append({'time': x[0], 'value': x[1]}, ignore_index=True)

df
```

The data frame looks like:

```
        time        value
0   1520529900.000  24.333
1   1520530260.000  16.333
2   1520530320.000  10.500
3   1520530380.000  34.000
4   1520530740.000  33.667
5   1520530800.000  26.667
6   1520531160.000  15.000
7   1520531220.000  25.000
8   1520531280.000  31.000
9   1520531640.000  42.000
10  1520531700.000  34.333
```

the time difference between each record is 60. However, there are missing data, so the time gap between records is sometimes > 60. How do I add records for missing data by making all time difference between records = 60 and the missing value as -1? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can set `time` as an index, reindex it so that you have all index values with 60 seconds interval and fill NaN's with `-1`:

```
In [242]: df.set_index('time').reindex(np.arange(df['time'].min(), df['time'].max(), 60)) \
            .fillna(-1) \
            .reset_index()
Out[242]:
            time   value
0   1.520530e+09  24.333
1   1.520530e+09  -1.000
2   1.520530e+09  -1.000
3   1.520530e+09  -1.000
4   1.520530e+09  -1.000
5   1.520530e+09  -1.000
6   1.520530e+09  16.333
..           ...     ...
23  1.520531e+09  31.000
24  1.520531e+09  -1.000
25  1.520531e+09  -1.000
26  1.520531e+09  -1.000
27  1.520532e+09  -1.000
28  1.520532e+09  -1.000
29  1.520532e+09  42.000

[30 rows x 2 columns]
```